# SQL Server Constraints Across Tables

Tags: sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

I have a SQL Server database with an `Apartment` table (which has columns `FloorNum` and `BuildingID`) and an `ApartmentBuilding` table (with column `NumFloors`). Is there any way to set up a constraint (using the SQL Server UI) to check that `Apartment.FloorNum` is greater than `ApartmentBuilding.NumFloors`?

I tried this:

```
FloorNum > ApartmentBuilding.NumFloors
```

but now I realize that I somehow have to join the columns on the `BuildingID`, but I have no idea how to do that within a constraint.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a CHECK CONSTRAINT since it requires data from another table. You would handle this with an [INSERT/UPDATE trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure out how to do it! Thanks for stopping me from wasting my time

Answer (score 0):

1. In ApartmentBuilding table, add UNIQUE constraint on(BuildingID, NumFloors)
2. In Apartment table, add column NumFloorsInBuilding
3. In Apartment table, add foreign key on (BuildingID, NumFloorsInBuilding) referring to (BuildingID, NumFloors). This guarantees that NumFloorsInBuilding is always equal to NumFloors in parent table.
4. In Apartment table, add CHECK(FloorNum < NumFloorsInBuilding)

Comment: Just adding a foreign key references doesn't magically fill the `BuildingID` column in the Apartment table. Of course - if you manually add the max. number of floors to each Apartment, then the CHECK constraint is a piece of cake - but that unnecessarily duplicates information that's already in the Building table....

Comment: Surely it duplicates information, no argument here. If you need rock solid integrity, this is the only way to go. If you tolerate some invalid data, then go for triggers.